# I'm having trouble using void functions in .NET fiddle

Tags: c#, .net-fiddle

I'm currently taking an It1050 class, and I'm new to coding. I'm having an issue with using void functions with their program. I wanted to know if anyone could help me solve the problem. There's something wrong with the website, and no matter what I, do I can't get the code to work. Even after my instructor gave me some guidance on what to do. I have a link to the code you can make changes to. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

https://dotnetfiddle.net/fcen52

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Function - A code block that contains a series 
        // of statements. A program causes the statements 
        // To be exucuted by calling the function 
        // and specifying anya required parameters.
        
        // void function a function that does NOT have a
        // return value.
        
        // function type - the type of value the function 
        // returns
        // function name - The name you call the function 
        
        // parameter - Information that is passed into functions 
        // A parameter acts as a variable inside a function
        
        greeting("Cole");
        greeting("John");
            
        void greeting(String name)
        { 
        
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name); 
        }  
        
        // name is not valid. You cannot use name here. :(
        
    }
    //TEACHER'S COMMENT:
    //Put your function outside of the main function scope
    //Put "public static" before the return type.
    
    //Example below:
    //public static void greeting(String name) { /* Your code goes here */ }
}
```

Comment: welcome - please post the code here.

Comment: read your teachers comments

Comment: Try this short lessons: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/csharp-code-blocks/  (maybe they explain it better than your teacher )

Comment: Use the .NET 5 or the Roslyn 3.8 complier. Local functions are newer c# concept the .NET 4.7.2 is not supporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods inside other methods, are called
[Local functions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) and are available since C# 7.0.

.NET fiddle is apparently not supporting C# 7.0 when you select the .NET 4.7.2 compiler. Select either the .NET 5 or the Roslyn 3.8 complier or alternatively move the function out of the `Main` method to the class-level and make it static (because you are calling it from `Main` which is static as well).

Comment: Thank you so much!! I changed over to .NET .5, and it worked perfectly. I have been at this for four hours. It's such a relief that I'm able to run the code.

Comment: Ok, will do! I just upvoted yours now. Like I said in my last comment, thank you so much. I felt like I was going insane.